# Export data from As400

Tags: export, ibm-midrange

I want to  export data from AS400 to flat file or csv file. Then I will try to load the text file into Oracle by using Oracle Sql Loader.

Do you have any experiences about exporting AS400 data? Which method I can follow for reaching best performance?

Answer (score 4):

The command `CPYTOIMPF` can export as a CSV file.

Also available is IBM i Navigator's Run SQL Script facility.  If you set the option to Allow Save, you can right click the results of a SELECT statement and save it as a CSV.

Another idea is to set up an ODBC connection and let Oracle connect directly to the IBM i's DB2 database.